# SQL: How to Select multiple columns with only one group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query table to get `DELIVERYCUSTOMER` without duplicate name
in one table.
For Example, consider the following table with picture(another detail is different) :

[image]

I try query like this

```
;WITH Cutomers as (
  select DELIVERYCUSTOMER
  from delivery_details
  group by DELIVERYCUSTOMER )
select
  m.DELIVERYADDRESS1,
  m.DELIVERYPHONE,
  m.contact_person,
  m.contact_address, 
  m.DELIVERYCUSTOMER, m.LATITUDE, m.LONGITUDE
from delivery_details as m
where DELIVERYCUSTOMER LIKE 'Sor%'
join Cutomers as c on c.DELIVERYCUSTOMER = m.DELIVERYCUSTOMER
```

the result is still show duplicate name

I just need when i search like `Bu` it's will show list of the customer start name is 'Bu' and i can get another detail to show such as address, phone, latitude, longitude

I run in my sql the data will show like

```
    SELECT DELIVERYCUSTOMER, DELIVERYADDRESS1, DELIVERYPHONE, contact_person, contact_address, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE 
FROM delivery_details WHERE DELIVERYCUSTOMER LIKE 'Bu%' GROUP BY DELIVERYCUSTOMER
```

I get data like this

[image]

and column in this table have more than 40+
I use this for get

**EDIT** :: I use this query to search DELIVERYCUTOMER to get name and another detail in this table so id,delivery_type,delivery_order, etc. is different

*Version of sql server is 2012*

Comment: There are more than one latitude and longitude for a single  `DELIVERYCUSTOMER`. If you dont want to repeat `DELIVERYCUSTOMER` then which `latitude/longitude` you will pick ?

Comment: if you select m.LATITUDE, m.LONGITUDE then its show you duplicate. so in select statement remove m.LATITUDE, m.LONGITUDE then it will display unique result

Comment: @swett.bp You can't do it, you will have to add the all the columns in `select` to `group by`

Comment: You should consider normalising your table

Comment: @Prdp actually all i select is use in the page another field in this table is different

Comment: @swett.bp, Can you let us know how you expect the output records will be?

Comment: @Aruna http://stackoverflow.com/a/41055241/5243077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is not normalized. What would it mean for instance to find the same address with another latitude and longitude? That should not even be possible in a database. So you might want separate tables for addresses, phones and contact persons instead.

Anyway, with the table given, it seems you just want to see one result row per customer and don't care which address, phone and contact.

Then this would suffice:

```
select 
  deliverycustomer,
  min(deliveryaddress1),
  min(deliveryphone),
  min(contact_person),
  min(contact_address)
from delivery_details
group by deliverycustomer
order by deliverycustomer;
```

If you want the phone to belong to the address and maybe even show latitude and logitude, then you wouldn't *Aggregate* rows, but *pick* rows instead. In order to do so, you'd rank your records per customer with `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
select
  deliverycustomer,
  deliveryaddress1,
  deliveryphone,
  contact_person,
  contact_address,
  latitude,
  longitude
from
(
  select 
    dd.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by deliverycustomer order by contact_person) as rn
  from delivery_details dd
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by deliverycustomer;
```

Comment: Don't mistaken me, just letting you know this answer has almost similar logic as I posted. I used CTE where you used a subquery to join. LOL :-)

Comment: @Aruna: Yes, it took me some time to type this and when I posted it, you had already written your answer. You are fast :-)

Comment: Ha ha, yeah I typed less than you as I thought OP had a knowledge in `CTE` already :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I can do already. Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below which uses `PARTITION BY` for the grouping and `ROW_NUMBER` to select one record as you expected.

This logic is useful since `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` have different values for the same customer.

```
;WITH Customers as (
  select 
    DELIVERYCUSTOMER,
    DELIVERYADDRESS1,
    DELIVERYPHONE,
    contact_person,
    contact_address,
    DELIVERYCUSTOMER,
    LATITUDE,
    LONGITUDE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERYCUSTOMER) AS RowNumber
  from delivery_details)

select
  *
from Customers Where RowNumber = 1 and DELIVERYCUSTOMER LIKE 'Sor%'
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhh

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
  select DISTINCT
  DELIVERYADDRESS1,
  DELIVERYPHONE,
  contact_person,
  contact_address, 
  DELIVERYCUSTOMER,
 LATITUDE,
LONGITUDE
from delivery_details
```

If values in all columns are same then you will get only 1 record.